# I can't save http-headers to the file by piping these to stream in node.js

Tags: node.js, http-headers

```
var fsHeaders = fs.createWriteStream('headers.html', 'utf-8');
var getHeaders = request('http://google.com', {method: 'HEAD'}, function (error, response, body)
{
    if (error || response.statusCode !== 200)
    {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
    {
        var tester = response.body;
        console.log(tester + 'response.body is EMPTY... so the headers are stored not in the "body"... \n');
        var targetHeaders = response.headers;
        body = body + JSON.stringify(targetHeaders);
        console.log(body + 'OK! \n');
    }
}).pipe(fsHeaders);
```

but my headers.html is empty... how to properly save response.headers to file? Can I later modify headers and sent them to the user without problem or it's restricted in some way? I want to get data from server, modify it via node, and send it to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you are using request or http module. When you request headers only with {method: 'HEAD'} method body is empty but headers are resident in response stream. I guess you problem is with requiring headers and display them as [objest Object]. You need to change object to string in that matter - to simply display it with console.log or pipe it to the file.

```
                        var targetHeaders = objectToString(resp.headers, targetHeaders);

                        function objectToString(object, outputString)
                        {
                            var outputString = '';
                            for (var i in object)
                            {
                                if (object.hasOwnProperty(i))
                                {
                                    outputString += i + ': ' + object[i] + ' \n';
                                }
                            }
                            return outputString;
                        }

now console.log(targetheaders); // OK! no [object Object] anymore :)
```

You can latter pass those headers without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, to verify that you are using `http.request`

Your problem also can be because request by default returns `buffer` and your stream is UTF-8 format.

Also the better way "catch" your headers might be by events that are emitted by http request:

```js
var postData = querystring.stringify({
  'msg': 'Hello World!'
});

var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

Comment: I'm using request module to request pages body/headers (var request = require('request');) I did try to... download... well request is a better word, html code of the target page and pipe it to the stream with utf-8 format and its working fine. Data is put in the proper file. I guess that headers request is not passed in a body variable or it's part of body that is separate from it's main content (html code)... you are probably right that it has buffer format. I'm gonna test it a little bit more without {method: 'HEAD'} property.

Comment: Oh, ok, i guess than headers are part of response object. Try with that.